# Calling child method from parent destructor in C++

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
  ~A() { release(); }
  virtual release() { cout << "~A"; } 
}

class B : public A {
  release() { cout << "~B"; }
}
```

When I delete B, only A class release() method is called.

What I want to achieve is for every child object, when it is deleted, I want to call release method which is overriden in each child class, without manually specifying destructor for each child with call to release (I'm lazy). Is this actually not possible to achieve in this or any other way?

Comment: Are you expecting *both* to be called?

Comment: No, only child release() method.

Comment: Destruction is supposed to start from the most derived type and work backwards to the base. If in the base you call a virtual release() method that is in a derived type whose destructor has already been called and thus has no valid members to access or do anything with. What do you expect to do. Even if it worked the way you expected (and it does not) you could not do anything useful so don't do it.

Comment: The question becomes what are you actually trying to achieve? You are supposed to clean up in the destructor so why not do it there.

Comment: I'm implementing object pool, so I will be reusing objects, but before that, I will need to clean them with release(). This way all my destructor code already resides in this release() method, so I thought why bother adding unnecessary destructor code... Figures it is necessary...

Comment: I don't see why you're trying to re-invent the C++ object system. Use placement new instead and actually create/destroy objects within your pool's memory.

Comment: I want to have all my objects in one big memory block, not many separate to avoid memory fragmentation and to increase performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Destructors* are executed in the reverse order of *constructors*, so when the `A` in a `B` is destroyed its `B` component has already been destroyed and no longer exists. Calling a method on a destroyed object yields *undefined behavior*, and that's why calls to *virtual methods* always resolve to the current class type within a *constructor* or *destructor*.

So basically no, you cannot do it. You will have to write them all.

Comment: Strange how I didn't thought about that myself, thanks, this completely makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't call virtual methods from destructors or constructors - they won't do what you expect them to do.

Quit being lazy and write destructors.

Answer (score 3):

A solution to this kind of problem is a pre-destroy phase, where you can manually control how destruction happens.

Implement your object with the `pImpl` pattern.  When the wrapping object is destroyed, inform the `pImpl` that it is going to be destroyed before destroying it.

`pImpl` can have a base `virtual PreDestroyable` class that allows child methods to register a `PreDestruction` callback, which you call during this pre destruction phase.

```
class Destroyable {
protected:
  Destroyable() {}; // must be empty
  virtual ~Destroyable() { Assert(PreDestroyers.empty()); };
  void RegisterPreDestroy( std::function<void()> const& func ) { PreDestroyers.push_back(func) );
private:
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> PreDestroyers;
public:
  // reverse order, reentrant:
  void PrepareToDie() {
    while (!PreDestroyers.empty()) {
      auto f = PreDestroyers.back();
      PreDestroyers.pop_back();
      f();
    }        
  }
};

// handles registration:
template<typename T>
class HasPreDestroyCode: public virtual Destroyable {
  // TODO: usual CRTP static or dynamic checks:
  T* self() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
  T const* self() const { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
  HasPreDestroyCode() {
    RegisterPreDestroy( [&]() { self()->PreDestroy(); } );
  }
  HasPreDestroyCode( HasPreDestroyCode const& other ) {
    RegisterPreDestroy( [&]() { self()->PreDestroy(); } );
  }
  HasPreDestroyCode( HasPreDestroyCode const& other ) {
    RegisterPreDestroy( [&]() { self()->PreDestroy(); } );
  }
private:
  HasPreDestroyCode& operator=( HasPreDestroyCode const& other ) = delete;
};

class Test: HasPreDestroyCode<Test> {
public:
  void PreDestroy() {}
};
```

I last wrote this stuff prior to C++11, so I haven't worked out how to handle move constructing it.  And it is all done at runtime, while it is probably possible to do something like the above with less runtime data.  Something like a list of types in the hierarchy that contain pre-destroy code or something?