# C++ Super class' destructor won't call overrided method

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super {
public:
    virtual ~Super() {
        func();
    }

    virtual void func() {
        cout << "super-class" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Super {
public:

    virtual void func() override {
        cout << "child-class" << endl;
    }

};


int main(void) {
    Super super;
    Child child;

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the default destructor of class `Child` is calling its super class `Super`'s `func()` instead of its own overrided `func()`. And the output was:

```
super-class
super-class
```

I've tried this solution below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super {
public:
    virtual ~Super() {
        func();
    }
    
    virtual void func() {
        cout << "super-class" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Super {
public:
    virtual ~Child() {
        func();
    }

    virtual void func() override {
        cout << "child-class" << endl;
    }

};


int main(void) {
    Super super;
    Child child;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output was:

```
child-class
super-class
super-class
```

But is there a way to let class `Child` automatically call its own `func()` in its destructor without `virtual ~Child()`?

Comment: In the destructor for `Super` the `Child ` has already called its destructor.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005070/calling-child-method-from-parent-destructor-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005070/calling-child-method-from-parent-destructor-in-c)

Comment: "*the default destructor of class Child is calling its super class Super's func()*" No, and the output you quoted does not show that. The destructor of Child calls `Child::func`, then the destructor of the Super parent class gets called, which calls `Super::func`.

Comment: @drescherjm nope I removed Supser super; get same result as he is getting

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the second code snippet with that comment. I just removed the comment because it's adding more confusion than helping.

Comment: Does't this invoke UB?

Comment: C++ works differently that many other languages (for ex. C#) in that case (and for constructor too).

Comment: Any workaround that got Child::func() to run from the destructor of Super would be UB.

Answer (score 3):

By the time a base class destructor has *started* running, the *derived* class(es) have already been fully destructed.  It (they) no longer exist(s).  They cannot be called into.  They are EX-objects!  (Loosely paraphrasing Herb, paraphrasing the John.)

Level by level, as the object dies, the parts of it that have been destroyed are *not* left behind; they no longer exist.  The type is adjusted accordingly upwards, and virtual calls resolve to the type being destroyed, until nothing is left of that object but a pile of bits.